# I want to make a custom form in NetSuite with a list of Status after enabling Inventory Status with no empty field option

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

```
`sublist.addField({
                id: 'INV_STATUS',
                label: 'INV_STATUS',
                type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT,
                source: 'inventorystatus'
            });`
```

I am using this code to add a field to sublist but the sublist has first value as empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have to populate the list manually to avoid an empty option.

```js
var list = sublist.addField({
  id: 'INV_STATUS',
  label: 'INV_STATUS',
  type: serverWidget.FieldType.SELECT
});

search.create({
  type: search.Type.INVENTORY_STATUS,
  columns: 'name'
}).run().each(function(result) {
  list.addSelectOption({
    value: result.id,
    text: result.getValue('name')
  });
});
```